# Picasso slider with pagerView. Get images drawable local images. And how to auto change image

Tags: java, android

I need slider for content_home.xml. I can with Picasso. But I want use local images in @drawable/images, and when I want auto change images every 5 seconds.

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


private String[] imageUrls = new String[]{
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/11/23/34/cat-1817970_960_720.jpg", ---> i change these images @
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/21/12/26/glowworm-3031704_960_720.jpg",
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/24/09/09/road-3036620_960_720.jpg",
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/07/00/07/fantasy-2925250_960_720.jpg",
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/10/15/28/butterfly-2837589_960_720.jpg"
```

---> i change these images "@drawable/images..." (local images)

```
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageUrls);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

content_home.xml

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    tools:context="com.codinginflow.picassoimagesliderexample.MainActivity">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.example.hassucuk;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private String[] imageUrls;

    ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(imageUrls[position])

                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);
        container.addView(imageView);

        return imageView;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to automatically change the slider after some period of time ?

Comment: yes example :  every 5 seconds.

Comment: Please edit your old question instead of posting a new one. There's absolutely no shame in editing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code and you are good to go.!!

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (view_pager.getCurrentItem() == dotsCount - 1) {
                        page = 0;
                    }
                    view_pager.setCurrentItem(page++, true);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 500, 5000);
```

Comment: You are perfect :) . I'm new developer this code working successfully. But can you explain this code for my learning :)

Comment: Sure. See timer is a class in java which helps you in do a specific task after some period of time. and timer class has a method scheduleAtFixedRate which helps you in doing a repeated task at a specific time frame. and view pager has a method to set the current item. and according to position of page it will automatically change the page after the time alloted to timer task

Comment: Its working but this issue =  1.image load after 5sec -> 2.image load after 5s 3.image load after 5s its okey auto load successfully. Now show final image. When finish process. Not return to back to 1.image . And dont auto load when finish

Comment: what is the issue buddy ?

Comment: i explain this issue once 25 mins :)

Comment: Okey , slider images auto load but  not load when final image.

Comment: You meant to say it is not changing to last image ?

Comment: This is a perfectly working code. As I have integrated into one of my projects.

Comment: I fixed this issue  :) Your codes are working perfect :))